# чтение вектора структур из файла

Tags: c++, c++builder-xe

есть структура

```
struct Record
{
      int Score;
      UnicodeString Name;
};
```

есть вектор

```
    std::vector<Record> list;
```

код для записи структуры в файл

```
std::ofstream out("output.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
std::vector<Record>::size_type size = list.size();
out.write((char*)&list, sizeof(size));
out.write((char*)&list[0], list.size() * sizeof(Record));
out.close();
```

код для чтения

```
std::ifstream is("output.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::vector<Record>::size_type size = 0;
is.read((char*)&size, sizeof(size));
list.resize(size);
is.read((char*)&list[0], list.size() * sizeof(Record));
is.close();
```

проблема в том что данные либо не записываются(хотя в файле есть изменения, но т.к. он бинарный сложно определить что записалось), либо не читается(что вероятнее т.к. новый вектор имеет размер 0)

`UnicodeString` - тип строки(все компоненты обычно в текстовых свойствах принимают/возвращают данный тип).
Проект делаю в RAD Studio 10.2

Comment: Поясните в чем проблема. Что из себя представляет `UnicodeString`?

Comment: @Cerbo добавил в описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы все делаете не правильно.

Во-первых здесь вы записываете не размер, а первые `sizeof(size)` байтов объекта `list`:

```
out.write((char*)&list, sizeof(size));
```

видимо имелось в виду:

```
out.write((char*)&size, sizeof(size));
```

К стати, называть объект вектора именем `list`, мягко скажу, не удачная идея.

Во-вторых, запись и чтение самих элементов у вас так же не правильная. Разберем ваше выражение:

```
out.write((char*)&list[0], list.size() * sizeof(Record));
```

1. `(char*)&list[0]` здесь вы получаете указатель на первый элемент массива и приводите его к указателю на `char`, к стати если выше вы не проверяете размер вектора и если он окажется пустым, то здесь бросится исключение;
2. `list.size() * sizeof(Record)` определяете размер массива в байтах, это правильно;
3. поток записывает в файл непрерывный блок байтов размером `list.size() * sizeof(Record)` начиная с адреса `(char*)&list[0]`, при этом берутся непосредственно "сырые" байты прямо из памяти без разбора класс не класс, массив не массив;

При этом, поле `Score` запишется корректно потому, что оно имеет простой числовой тип. А вот поле `Name` запишется не так как вы, видимо, ожидаете. Запишется побайтовая копия непосредственно полей объекта `UnicodeString`, а не байты строки. Объект `UnicodeString` не содержит в себе байты строки, а только указатель на память где они лежат.

Чтобы корректно записать `UnicodeString` нужно получить указатель на блок памяти где непосредственно хранится строка (делается это с помощью функции `UnicodeString::data()`), корректно вычислить размер строки в байтах, и в таком виде записывать. Отдельно нужно обрабатывать пустые строки.

Чтение нужно делать в обратном порядке: вычитываете байты строки в промежуточный буфер, а потом передаете этот буфер в конструктор `UnicodeString`.